# Ignore Attached models when add new row - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following function in OrganizationTypeService

```
        public async Task<int> CreateOrganizationTypeAsync(User user, CreateOrganizationTypeModel createOrganizationTypeModel)
        {
            OrganizationType organizationType = new OrganizationType()
            {
                Name = createOrganizationTypeModel.Name,
                Account = user.account,
                Active = true
            };

            await _context.OrganizationTypes.AddAsync(organizationType);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return organizationType.ID;
        }
```

I call this function from my controller OrganizationsTypeController

```
                User user = await _identityService.GetCurrentUserAsync();
                if (! await _organizationTypeService.OrganizationTypeExistsByNameAsync(user, createOrganizationTypeModel.Name))
                {
                    var id = await _organizationTypeService.CreateOrganizationTypeAsync(user, createOrganizationTypeModel);
                    _logger.LogDebug(LoggingEvents.OrganizationTypeSuccess, "Organization Type Created");
                    _toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Organization Type Created");
                    return id;
                }
```

the GetUserAsyncMethod is

```
        public async Task<User> GetCurrentUserAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Users.Include(x => x.Account).ThenInclude(x=>x.StripePlan).ThenInclude(x => x.stripeTiers).Include(x => x.Account).ThenInclude(x => x.Organizations).Include(x => x.Account).ThenInclude(x => x.Billing).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _currentUserService.UserId);
        }
```

I get the error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Billing' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Now i can fix this if in the CreateOrganizationTypeAsync i do

```
            Account a = _context.Accounts.Find(user.Account.ID);
```

and assign the account in OrganizationType Model to a instead of using the user.Account.

```
            OrganizationType organizationType = new OrganizationType()
            {
                Name = createOrganizationTypeModel.Name,
                Account = a,
                Active = true
            };
```

Im assuming the issue is due to EF trying to add a new Billing Row into the table when it tries to create a new OrganizationType and cant because it already has an ID assigned to it. Is there anyway to tell EF to not do this when it does a Add for OrganizationType?

Basically i want to add a new Organization Type that is assigned to an account but dont want to change the GetCurrentUserAsync function to accommodate as this is used in other areas and also dont want to do a find in the Service for the account if i dont have to.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to tell EF to not do this when it does a Add for
> OrganizationType?

You can assign a value to the field which is identity field when adding data.

You only need to execute the statement `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON;` before adding the saved data.

Here is an example:

```
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Post ON");
        var post = new Post()
        {
            Id = 12,
            Title = "newdata",
        };
        context.Post.Add(post);

        context.SaveChanges();
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Post OFF");
```